# Join before a date as <= and the =

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have subquery A and need to do a left join with subquery B, but the b.partition_date must be greater equal than a.partition_date until 2023-01-01 and then the two must be equal. In fact, on table A I have dates starting from mid-2022 and on B only from 2023, but from the join I must have the data valued for all the dates of A (so I can't just do a join with equal dates). Ideas on how to do it? I'm using Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*... b.partition_date must be greater equal than a.partition_date until 2023-01-01*

```
a.partition_date <= date '2023-01-01' and b.partition_date >= a.partition_date
```

*and then the two must be equal*

```
a.partition_date > date '2023-01-01' and b.partition_date = a.partition_date
```

Together:

```
select something
from  A
left join B on 
  ( a.partition_date <= date '2023-01-01' and b.partition_date >= a.partition_date )
  or 
  ( a.partition_date > date '2023-01-01' and b.partition_date = a.partition_date )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much detail, but here is an example that uses a case expression in the join condition:

```
WITH subquery_a AS (
  SELECT partition_date, column1, column2
  FROM table_a
),
subquery_b AS (
  SELECT partition_date, column3, column4
  FROM table_b
)
SELECT *
FROM subquery_a
LEFT JOIN subquery_b
ON subquery_a.partition_date = 
  CASE
    WHEN subquery_a.partition_date <= '2023-01-01' 
    THEN subquery_b.partition_date
    ELSE DATE('2023-01-01')
  END;
```